# Create a Popup Window

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

I have a list of results that are returned from a form being posted. The results are standard contact information: Name, Address, City, State, Zip, etc. There is a hidden field that is the primary key of the database.

The user has the option to go through this table of people and click on a row for more detailed information. I would like this to be a popup but can't figure it out.

Here is what I have tried.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

   $('tr.myRow').click(function () {
     var test = $(this).find('td.hidden').html();
     $.ajax(
     {
        url: '@Url.Action("Details", "Record")',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { recordID: test }
     });
   });
});
```

Comment: add a `success` handler to your ajax call that pops open a new window.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments you just need to add a `success` function to your code and pop up the window in there.

I used just a stub just in case you wanted to use a modal or whatever else you prefer.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

   $('tr.myRow').click(function () {
     var test = $(this).find('td.hidden').html();
     $.ajax(
     {
        url: '@Url.Action("Details", "Record")',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { recordID: test },
        success: function(data) {
            //popup code here
        }
     });
   });
});
```